# font awesome dom.watch vs dom.i2svg which one is better for saving memory resources?

Tags: font-awesome

Having a question, but can't find an answer from https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/with-the-api/methods/dom-watch Does `dom.watch()` consume more memory?

If talking about a dynamic website, and from saving ram resource prospective, is it better to use multiple times `dom.i2svg()` that where is necessary or just use `dom.watch()`?  Thanks!